# Openshift/OKD - how to template docker secrets

Tags: openshift, okd

As a admin with a lot of parameterized Openshift Templates, I am struggling to create a parameterized SECRET objects in the templates for type kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson or kubernetes.io/dockercfg so that the secret can be used for docker pulls.

Challenge:Everything is pre-base64 encoded in JSON format for normal dockerconfigjson template setup, and not sure how to change it.

The Ask: How to create a SECRET template that takes parameters ${DOCKER_USER}, ${DOCKER_PASSWORD}, ${DOCKER_SERVER}, and ${DOCKER_EMAIL} to then create the actual secret that can be used to pull docker images from a private/secured docker registry.

This is to replace commandline "oc create secret docker-registry ...." techniques by putting them in a template file stored within gitlab/github to have a gitOps style deployment pattern.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The format of the docker configuration secrets can be found in the documentation (or in your cluster via `oc export secret/mysecret`) under the [Using Secrets](https://docs.okd.io/latest/dev_guide/secrets.html#dev-guide-secrets-using-secrets) section.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: aregistrykey
  namespace: myapps
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson 
data:
  .dockerconfigjson:<base64encoded docker-config.json>
```

One method would be to accept the pre-based64 encoded contents of the json file in your template parameters and stuff them into the data section.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: aregistrykey
  namespace: myapps
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson 
data:
  .dockerconfigjson:${BASE64_DOCKER_JSON}
```

Another method would be to use the stringData field of the secret object. As noted on the same page:

> Entries in the stringData map are converted to base64 and the entry will then be moved to the data map automatically. This field is write-only; the value will only be returned via the data field.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: aregistrykey
  namespace: myapps
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson 
stringData:
  .dockerconfigjson:${REGULAR_DOCKER_JSON}
```

The format of the actual *value* of the .dockerconfigjson key is the same as the contents of the `.docker/config.json` file. So in your specific case you might do something like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: aregistrykey
  namespace: myapps
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson 
stringData:
  .dockerconfigjson:'{"auths": {"${REGISTRY_URL}": {"auth": "${BASE64_USERNAME_COLON_PASSWORD}"}}}'
```

Unfortunately the template langugage OpenShift uses for templates isn't quite powerful enough to base64 encode the actual paramter values for you, so you can't quite escape having to encode the `username:password` pair outside of the template itself, but your CI/CD tooling should be more than capable of performing this with raw username/password strings.

Comment: Thanks Nick, independently came to the same conclusion for the base64 encoding required for the auth value, but this is something I can work from, thanks!
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: aregistrykey
  namespace: myapps
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson 
stringData:
  .dockerconfigjson:'{"auths": {"${REGISTRY_URL}": {"auth": "${BASE64_USERNAME_COLON_PASSWORD}"}}}'